# Matriz com Strings em C++

Tags: c++, string, matriz

Gostaria de criar uma matriz MxN em C++ para armazenar strings, como a matriz abaixo:

```
[['3325309756482910474',  'CARRO',  '2506794813021649539', '618.57'],
 ['3325309756485249504',  'MOTO',  2506794813021649539',   '649.32'],
 ['3328687456208678517',  'BIKE',  '2506794813021649539',  '649.43']]
```

Seria possível? Tentei e não consegui.

```
auto MatrizString() {
    string m = NULL;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            m[i][j] = "Numes";
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%s", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E onde está o código que você tentou e qual erro foi reportado? Será que você não deveria utilizar `{` e `}` no lugar de `[` e `]`?

Comment: Adicionei o código. O erro relatado é: "a expressão deve possuir tipo ponteiro-para-objeto".

Comment: Mas `m` é uma string ou um array de strings?

Comment: Um array de strings.  O certo seria eu colocar m[]? E como, a partir disso, eu conseguiria criar uma matriz?

Comment: @BrunaCastro você declarou uma string não uma matriz de strings o certo seria `string m[4][4];`  , na segunda linha, para uma matrix 4x4.

Comment: @user72726, fiz a substituição e deu certo. Porém, o print fica com caracteres estranhos: `·┘8·┘T·┘p·┘
î·┘¿·┘─·┘Ó·┘
³·┘¹┘4¹┘P¹┘
l¹┘ê¹┘ñ¹┘└¹┘`

Comment: Devo importar alguma biblioteca?

Comment: Já que estás a programar em C++, considere usar `cout` ao invés de `printf`. Mas se você realmente quer usar printf, deve primeiramente converter a string de C++  para C antes de imprimir. Ex: `printf("%s", m[i][j].c_str())`

Comment: Deu certinho, vlw por ter ajudado @user72726!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classe vector pode facilitar sua vida:

```
  vector<vector<string>> matriz({
    { "3325309756482910474", "CARRO", "2506794813021649539", "618.57"} ,
    {"3325309756485249504",  "MOTO",  "2506794813021649539", "649.32" },
    { "3328687456208678517", "BIKE",  "2506794813021649539", "649.43" }
  });
```

Ela tem métodos que permite inserir/remover elementos sem necessidade de manipular diretamente a memória. Se você quiser adicionar um novo elemento no final por exemplo:

```
 matriz.push_back({"a", "b", "c", "d"});
```

Sem contar que caso você deseje que alguma linha contenha uma quantidade diferente de elementos, é só adicionar a mais ou a menos:

```
 matriz.push_back({"linha de elemento unico"});
```

Dá uma conferida na documentação pra conferir as demais possibilidades.

Answer (score 1):

- Acho que sabe que tem apenas 3 linhas aqui

```
[['3325309756482910474',  'CARRO',  '2506794813021649539', '618.57'],
 ['3325309756485249504',  'MOTO',  2506794813021649539',   '649.32'],
 ['3328687456208678517',  'BIKE',  '2506794813021649539',  '649.43']]
```

e 4 no trecho que postou e que é uma função em C, apesar de ter usado a tag C++

Em C++ use uma classe. É mais simples.

#### auto

`auto` em C tem outro significado. Não é uma definição de tipo. Em C++ auto não se aplica a esse contexto, como o compilador deve ter dito.

Em C++ pode escrever

```
    string m[4][4] =
    {
        { "3325309756482910474", "CARRO", "2506794813021649539", "618.57"} ,
        {"3325309756485249504",  "MOTO",  "2506794813021649539", "649.32" },
        { "3328687456208678517", "BIKE",  "2506794813021649539", "649.43" }
    };
```

Se preferir declarar "Matriz" pode até escrever

```
using Matriz = string[4][4];
```

Como nesse exemplo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using Matriz = string[4][4];

int main(void)
{
    string m[4][4] =
    {
        { "3325309756482910474", "CARRO", "2506794813021649539", "618.57"} ,
        {"3325309756485249504", "MOTO",   "2506794813021649539", "649.32" },
        { "3328687456208678517", "BIKE",  "X506794813021649539", "649.43" }
    };
    Matriz uma{};
    uma[3][3] = m[2][2];
    cout << "M[3][3] = \"" << uma[3][3] << "\"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Que mostra o esperado

```
M[3][3] = "X506794813021649539"
```

Use uma classe e escreva os métodos como precisa deles. Ou mesmo os operadores para Matriz.